# Error al crear base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero crear una base de datos y tengo 3 archivos: bd.sql, bd.mdf y bd_log.ldf
Al abrir el archivo SQL:
Codigo:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [PROYECTOS\PRUEBA\APP_DATA\BD.MDF]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'bd', FILENAME = N'C:\Users\MC.cover\Desktop\Prueba\bd.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'bd_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Users\MC.cover\Desktop\Prueba\_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
GO
```

ALTER DATABASE [PROYECTOS\PRUEBA\APP_DATA\BD.MDF] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 130
GO

Al ejecutar este archivo sql me aparecen los siguientes errores:

1. Error al buscar el archivo "C:\Users\MC.cover\Desktop\Prueba\bd.mdf" en los directorios, error del sistema operativo: 5(Acceso denegado.)
2. Error de CREATE DATABASE. No se pueden crear algunos de los archivos de la lista. Consulte los errores relacionados.
3. El usuario no tiene permiso para modificar la base de datos

Al buscar en internet me tope con que podía ser que no tuviese el usuario acceso de administrador cosa que recordaba que si tenia permisos; verifiqué nuevamente por si las dudas y efectivamente mi usuario tiene permisos administrador sobre todos los archivos en la PC.

¿Qué puede ser?

Comment: ¿Què versión de SQL Server estás utilizando?

Comment: El usuario de servicio tiene acceso de escritura al disco?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tu login no tiene los permisos suficientes para alterar cualquier base de datos y no tienes un usuario que permita alterar la base de datos recien creada. Podrías intentar crear un usuario que pueda alterar la base de datos antes de cambiar el nivel de compatibilidad.

Para revisar tus permisos, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER')
WHERE [permission_name] = 'ALTER ANY DATABASE';
SELECT *
FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('PROYECTOS\PRUEBA\APP_DATA\BD.MDF', 'DATABASE')
WHERE [permission_name] = 'ALTER';
```

Te recomiendo utilizar un nombre más adecuado a tu base de datos en vez de nombrarla según el archivo físico.

Comment: Estoy ingresando con el usuario sa. Me fije que tuviese los permisos administrador para cualquier cosa y los tiene. por si las dudas cree un usuario nuevo y le di todos los permisos y al ejecutar el codigo con cualquiera de los 2 usuarios el problema se repite

Comment: y si te logueas con las credenciales de windows?

Comment: El mismo resultado